# How to execute selection correctly on a child element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, function

Can I kindly ask to help me with jQuery logic, I have a gallery with multiple album views and I want to trigger a common opening of the modal window on each of them, where I play a sider with the slick.js plugin

```
$(".open").on("click",[".popup-modal, .popup-content"], function handler( event ) {
var target = $( event.target );
    target.children().addClass("active");});
```

HTML here:

```
<div class="popup-modal">
 <div class="popup-content">
   <div class="carousel-inside-gallery">
    <div><img src="../assets/photo/1.jpg" alt="" /> 
         </div>
    <div><img src="../assets/photo/2.jpg" alt=""  > 
         </div>
    <div><img src="../assets/photo/2.jpg" alt="" /> 
         </div>
 </div>
```

I want to be able to specify $(this) property on button somehow. Or if there is a better stratedy towards this task?

Comment: I don't see a button.

Comment: it was higher a bit

<button class="open">View gallery</button>

Comment: Please create a working [mcve], using the `<>` button in editor. You can link resources from cdn sources and you should place the relevant code in each of the provided panels. Without your markup structure it's impossible to determine what would make it work.